# How to download the latest i8kutils package and install it properly?

Tags: 13.10, fan, inspiron, fancontrol, heat

My laptop is **Dell Inspiron SE 7520**, Ubuntu **13.10**.

I learned that i8kutils is an awesome tool to control the fan speed automatically (The fan speed issue frustrates me tremendously).

I need to be able to do the following:

1. Configure it properly (It doesn't start when Ubuntu starts)
2. Understand it's configurations (I **think** I only have one fan, I need to know how to configure based on that)
3. How to know if I have more than one fan ?!
4. I need to install the latest version (**1.39** for saucy/13.10), while when I run it, it shows it's version as **1.27** !

I also have an **ATI Radeon Hd 7730M** graphics card, how to know if this one has a fan too ?!